# Tailwind custom theme prefix like dark:{class}

Tags: plugins, tailwind-css, themes, darkmode

I am working on a site that has two types of customers "b2c" & "b2b". I want to style the pages differently depending on which type of customer accesses the page.

Is there a way to define a custom tailwind theme prefix like `b2c:bg-blue-400` & `b2b:bg-green-400`

I have seen examples of this done fx. [headlessui tabs](https://headlessui.com/vue/tabs#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20Tailwind%20CSS%2C%20you%20can%20use%20the%20%40headlessui/tailwindcss%20plugin%20to%20target%20this%20attribute%20with%20modifiers%20like%20ui%2Dopen%3A*%3A)

Futhermore is it possible to also allow dark mode options like `b2c:text-black dark:b2c:text-white`

I've tried to modify the default theme, but I cannot find a solution that lets me choose between two different class options depending on a given theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using a Tailwind Plugin to register custom [static variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-variants). For example, if b2c and b2b are to be identified by some parent class `b2c` and `b2b` respectively, you could do:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // …
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('b2c', '.b2c &');
      addVariant('b2b', '.b2b &');
    }),
  ],
};
```

These would then allow you to use class names like `b2c:bg-blue-400` and  `b2b:bg-green-400`, which would generate CSS like:

```css
.b2c .b2c\:bg-blue-400 {
  …
}

.b2b .b2b\:bg-green-400 {
  …
}
```

Additionally, these new variants will automatically work with other variants, like `dark:b2c:text-white`, which would geneate something like:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
  .b2c .dark\:b2c\:text-white {
    …
  }
}
```